# Input type number me suma números de más cuando incremento el valor con la rueda del mouse

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para poder probar spritesheets para videojuegos y en los campos de configuración tengo varios inputs de tipo número.
Tengo una función que detecta la rueda del ratón y cambia el valor dentro del campo dependiendo para que lado gires las rueda y cuál sea el máximo que se puede ingresar en el campo. El método funciona como debería, el problema es que cuando hago click en el input y DESPUES uso la rueda del mouse me suma 1 de más al valor final, haciendo que se desplaze de 2 en 2 y no sé que genera ese comportamiento.
Si hago click afuera del input y pierde el foco vuelve cambiar el valor de 1 en 1 como debería.
P.D.:Para poder ingresar valores en los últimos campos hay que incrementar "Frame size".

```js
// CODIGO RELEVANTE PARA LA PREGUNTA
const KEY_PRESSED = {};

function setInputNumberValue(e) {
    const deltaY = e.deltaY;
    const input = e.target;

    let inputValueVariation = 1;
    let symbol = 1;
    
    if (KEY_PRESSED.shift) inputValueVariation = 5;
    if (KEY_PRESSED.shift && KEY_PRESSED.alt) inputValueVariation = 10;
    if (deltaY > 0) symbol = -1;
    
    const finalValue = Number(input.value) + (inputValueVariation * symbol);

        if (finalValue >= input.max) return input.value = input.max;
    else if (finalValue <= input.min) return input.value = input.min;
    else return input.value = finalValue;
}

function setMaxNumberOfRows(inputValue) {
    // Maximum canvas width/height resolution in chrome: 32,767px.
    const MAX_CAVAS_RESOLUTION = 32767;
    const MAX_NUM_OF_ROWS = Math.floor(MAX_CAVAS_RESOLUTION / inputValue);

    document.querySelectorAll(".max-frame-count").forEach(element =>
        element.innerHTML = `, the maximum number is ${MAX_NUM_OF_ROWS}`
    );

    document.getElementById("sprite-frame-start").max = MAX_NUM_OF_ROWS;
    document.getElementById("sprite-frame-end").max = MAX_NUM_OF_ROWS;
    document.getElementById("sprite-frame-row").max = MAX_NUM_OF_ROWS;
}

document.querySelectorAll(".input-number").forEach(input => 
    input.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
        if (e.target.id === "sprite-frame-size")
            return setMaxNumberOfRows(setInputNumberValue(e));
        else setInputNumberValue(e);
    })
);

document.querySelectorAll(".info-button").forEach(button =>
    button.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
        const target = e.target;
        const brotherElementsOfTarget = Array.from(target.parentNode.parentNode.children);
        const infoBox = brotherElementsOfTarget.find(element => element.className === "info");

        infoBox.style.display = "block";
        infoBox.style.width = "200px";
        infoBox.style.height = "min-content";
        infoBox.style.overflowY = "scroll";
        infoBox.style.left = `${target.offsetLeft}px`;
        infoBox.style.top = `${target.offsetTop - infoBox.offsetHeight}px`;
    })
);

document.querySelectorAll(".info-button").forEach(button =>
    button.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
        const target = e.target;
        const brotherElementsOfTarget = Array.from(target.parentNode.parentNode.children);
        const infoBox = brotherElementsOfTarget.find(element => element.className === "info");

        infoBox.style.display = "none";
    })
);

function keyDown(e) {
    KEY_PRESSED[e.key.toLocaleLowerCase()] = true;
}

function keyUp(e) {
    KEY_PRESSED[e.key.toLocaleLowerCase()] = false;
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);

// PARA FACILITAR EL TESTEO

document.getElementById("configure-sprite").addEventListener("submit", (e) => e.preventDefault())
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-display: block;
}

/* Diplay none */
input[type=file] {
    display: none;
}

* {
    gap: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Arial', cursive;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body {
    background-color: #a07a52;
    padding: 4px;
    user-select: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #473524;
}

div {
    display: contents;
    gap: 2px;
}

canvas {
    background-color: #eadbac;
    border: 5px solid #473524;
}

label, input {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: 'Arial', cursive;
    font-size: 16px;

    & input[type=checkbox]:hover {
        border: 4px solid #eadbac;
    }
}

label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    appearance: none;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #ee5e5c;
    border: 4px solid #473524;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: #5cee66;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 178px;
}

.config-input {
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #eadbac;
    border: 5px solid #473524;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: start;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #a07a52;
}

.config-input:hover, #label-input-sprite:hover {
    background-color: #a07a52;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #eadbac;
}

.input-title {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0px 8px;
    background-color: #473524;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #eadbac;

    & .info-button {
        border: 0;
        width: min-content;
        background-color: #473524;  
        align-self: flex-end;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: #a07a52;
        cursor: help;
        padding: 0px 4px;
    }
}

.info {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #eadbac;
    border: 5px solid #473524;
    padding: 4px;
}

#section-canvas {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 4px;
}

#label-input-sprite {
    background-color: #c8a279;
    border: 5px solid #473524;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#canvas-title {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #473524;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #eadbac;
}

form {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 1fr 0.5fr 1fr;
    gap: 4px 4px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "b c d e"
        "b c d e"
        "f g a a"
        "f g a a";
}

.a {
    grid-area: a;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    gap: 4px;
}

.b {
    gap: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-area: b;

    & * {
        width: -webkit-fill-available;;
    }
}

.c {
    gap: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-area: c;

    & * {
        width: -webkit-fill-available;;
    }
}

.d {
    gap: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-area: d;

    & * {
        width: -webkit-fill-available;;
    }
}

.e {
    gap: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-area: e;

    & * {
        width: -webkit-fill-available;;
    }
}

.f {
    gap: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-area: f;

    & * {
        width: -webkit-fill-available;;
    }
}

.g {
    gap: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    grid-area: g;

    & * {
        width: -webkit-fill-available;;
    }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #a07a52;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Spritesheet Tester</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section-canvas">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 0px;">
            <p id="canvas-title">Canvas</p>
            <canvas id="sprite-display"></canvas>
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <input type="file" id="input-sprite" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
            <label for="input-sprite" id="label-input-sprite"><p>UPLOAD SPRITESHEET</p></label>
            
            <form id="configure-sprite">
                <div class="a">
                    <label class="config-input" for="can-animate">
                        Animate sprite
                        <input type="checkbox" id="can-animate">
                    </label>
                    
                    <input class="config-input" type="submit" value="CONFIRM">
                </div>
                
                <div class="b">
                    <p class="input-title">
                        Display size
                        <input class="info-button" type="button" value="?">
                    </p>

                    <p class="info" style="display: none;">
                        The size in pixels at which the image will be displayed on the canvas, the maximum number is 512px.
                    </p>
                    
                    <input class="config-input input-number" type="number" value="0" id="sprite-size" step=".0" min="0" max="512">
                </div>
                
                <div class="c">
                    <p class="input-title">
                        Frame size
                        <input class="info-button" type="button" value="?">
                    </p>

                    <p class="info" style="display: none;">
                        The size in pixels of each frame of the sprite sheet, the maximum number is 256px.
                    </p>
                    
                    <input class="config-input input-number" type="number" value="1" id="sprite-frame-size" step=".0" min="1" max="256">
                </div>
                
                <div class="d">
                    <p class="input-title">
                        Frame rate
                        <input class="info-button" type="button" value="?">
                    </p>

                    <p class="info" style="display: none;">
                        The number of frames per second of the animation, the maximum number is 60.
                    </p>
                    
                    <input class="config-input input-number" type="number" value="0" id="sprite-frame-rate" step=".0" min="0" max="60">
                </div>
                
                <div class="e">
                    <p class="input-title">
                        Start frame
                        <input class="info-button" type="button" value="?">
                    </p>

                    <p class="info" style="display: none;">
                        The frame at which the animation begins<span class="max-frame-count">, the maximum number will be calculated after setting the frame size</span>.
                    </p>
                    
                    <input class="config-input input-number" type="number" value="0" id="sprite-frame-start" step=".0" min="0" max="10">
                </div>
                
                <div class="f">
                    <p class="input-title">
                        End frame
                        <input class="info-button" type="button" value="?">
                    </p>

                    <p class="info" style="display: none;">
                        The frame at which the animation ends<span class="max-frame-count">, the maximum number will be calculated after a the frame size is setled</span>.
                    </p>
                    
                    <input class="config-input input-number" type="number" value="0" id="sprite-frame-end" step=".0" min="0" max="10">
                </div>
                
                <div class="g">
                    <p class="input-title">
                        Row number
                        <input class="info-button" type="button" value="?">
                    </p>

                    <p class="info" style="display: none;">
                        The row of the sprite sheet that will be animated<span class="max-frame-count">, the maximum number will be calculated after a the frame size is setled</span>.
                    </p>
                    
                    <input class="config-input input-number" type="number" value="0" id="sprite-frame-row" step=".0" min="0" max="10">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <script src="https://leandrojofre.github.io/game-chaotic-alpha/classes/Sprite.js"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comportamiento natural (*default*)) de un `input[type=number]` es aumentar el valor (según el atributo `step`) con la rueda cuando se agrega el evento `wheel`

Prueba el siguiente código y verás que sin agregar nada más, el input aumenta y disminuye con la rueda.

```js
conEvento.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  //nada
});
```

```html
<input type="number" step="3"  placeholder="Sin evento" >

<input id="conEvento" type="number" step="3" placeholder="Con evento" >
```

Al agregar código adicional lo que haces es provocar el aumento (o disminución) 2 veces (el *default* + el tuyo). Para evitar este comportamiento *default* debes usar  `e.preventDefault();`

```
function setInputNumberValue(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //<- ESTO
    const deltaY = e.deltaY;
    const input = e.target;

   //etc
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! LLevo toda la tarde con esto y encontre el error justo cuando estaba cerrando todo. La próxima me toca mirar bien que hace addEventListener con cada elemento que lo use.

Comment: @Leandro A que bien!! Es que el comportamiento es bien extraño, ya que solo funciona al agregar el evento `wheel` aun cuando este no haga nada. (al menos en chrome y en edge). Yo busqué en la documentación y no encontré nada al respecto que mencionara dicho comportamiento. Por tanto era bien difícil detectar el problema. Suerte en el proyecto!!

Comment: todos los dias aprendo algo nuevo ...